# Earnshaw's theorem and Effective potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, electrostatics, equilibrium, stability

Earnshaw's theorem says "no stable equilibrium for any $\frac{1}{r}$ potential field in charge-free space". Now I am confused in some aspects, and I would like some helping hands.

1. General physics Textbooks draw a picture of potential field versus distance about electrons around nuclei, there is a place for local minimum (and therefore, it is nice to use a "spring approximation" around that point).
   That sounds kind of contradiction to me, would anyone be kind enough explaining that to me?

   - It seems exactly same reason below listed - where nuclei much massive than electrons, so to a good approximation - a stable circular motion.
2. Does this theorem work on varying-potential-field as well?

   - It seems not. considering planetary motion's reduced mass effective potential energy $V(r)_{eff}=U(r)+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}$, which reduce a two-bodies motion to one-body-motion, then there is a $r$ such that the one-body-motion along r direction at a stable equilibrium.  But if back to **an inertial frame**, then it also seem we do **NO** have such stable equilibrium (if $m_1$~$m_2$ )?

[image]

3. Do we need quantum theory to explain why we have a solid object (in a reasonable time scale ~10^3 years) due to no stable equilibrium for static inverse square force?

   - Even if above effective potential energy works, it doesn't save that, since to my knowledge, there is no way to reduce N-bodies-motion to one-body-motion, as well as atoms in a solid object just don't do "planetary motion" to each other!

---

4. Not sure if it is a physics question: Does "stable circular motion" count as "stable equilibrium" in r direction?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to make a trap that is stable in some direction(s). Just not one that is stable against deviations in all directions.

Your circular motion also encircles a region with charge, so you are not confining the circling charge within a charge free region.